# open-mpi: invalid message type-15

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, gfortran, openmpi

I was trying to run a few codes on open mpi  in fortran, things were working fine, until suddenly it stopped working and started displaying "invalid message type:15" (It compiles perfectly). Tried reinstalling open-mpi, did not help. What should I do?
I use the latest version of open-mpi.

CODE:

```
program basic
include 'mpif.h'

integer SIZE
parameter(SIZE=4)
integer numtasks,rank,ierr

call MPI_INIT(ierr)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,numtasks,ierr)
print*,rank

call MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)

end
```

The error received after successful compilation, while running:

```
[cgh-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:24051] [[49070,0],0] mca_oob_tcp_recv_handler: invalid message type: 15
[cgh-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:24051] [[49070,0],0] mca_oob_tcp_recv_handler: invalid message type: 15
[cgh-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:24051] [[49070,0],0] mca_oob_tcp_recv_handler: invalid message type: 15

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that the job aborted, but has no info as to the process
that caused that situation.
```

Comment: Did the working program suddenly stop working, or did you introduce a bug when editing it? Also, some code would be nice to look at, as it's rather difficult to debug invisible programs.

Comment: It was working fine few days back & stopped suddenly. It refuses to run **Any** code including simple hello world programs. Help!

Comment: I'm assuming that you didn't recompile the code after reinstalling OpenMPI? I'm wondering if there's a mismatch between your binary and the installed OpenMPI libraries.

Comment: What you *should do* is give us more information to reproduce or understand your issue. Post your code (even if it's a simple hello world!)! what changed? Which versions are you running? What is the exact, full error message?

Comment: Running openmpi version 1.10.2

Comment: coooo, do you have the same binary on all machines and the exactly same version of OpenMPI used on all machines? How did you start, how many machines are there in run. Is your configuration of OpenMPI transport correct?

Comment: Running the basic code on 1 pc , with 4 cores.

Comment: Show your commands for compiling and running the code.